# Alertdialoge has no "dismiss()" nor "cancel()" property, How should I force it to disappear?

Tags: java, android, android-alertdialog

As shown in the code, the `switchToGPSPreferences` method creates an `alertdialoge` and I can dismiss it while i am inside the `dialogeInterface` using `dialog.dismiss()`.

But the problem is, while i am inside `onProviderEnabled()` callback, `alertDialoge` has no `dismiss()` or `cancel()` property and I do not know how should I force it to disappear?

Code

```
private void switchToGPSPreferences() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "Inside Of switchToGPSPreferences()");
    this.alertDialogue = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    this.alertDialogue.setTitle("GPS Settings");
    this.alertDialogue.setCancelable(false);
    this.alertDialogue.setMessage(ALER_DIALOGUE_MSG);

    this.alertDialogue.setNeutralButton("Settings",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent gpsSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(gpsSettings, GPS_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    alertDialogue.create();
    alertDialogue.show();
}// End of showDialogueBox function.
...
...
...
...
@Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), USER_ENABLED_GPS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "GPS Enabled, onProviderEnabled()");
        if (alertDialogue != null) {
                       // here ii want to dismiss/destroy the `alertdialoge`
                     }

    }
```

***UPDATE***

Logcat_OutPut:

```
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533): java.lang.RuntimeException: Failure  delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=1, result=0, data=null} to activity  {com.example.meetingpointlocator_03/com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix}: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.AlertDialog$Builder cannot be cast to android.content.DialogInterface
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3518)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleSendResult(ActivityThread.java:3561)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$1200(ActivityThread.java:168)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1377)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5493)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
```

05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1209)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1025)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533): Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: android.app.AlertDialog$Builder cannot be cast to android.content.DialogInterface
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.showProgressDialog(MeetingPointFix.java:102)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.registerGPSListener(MeetingPointFix.java:225)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at com.example.meetingpointlocator_03.MeetingPointFix.onActivityResult(MeetingPointFix.java:181)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.Activity.dispatchActivityResult(Activity.java:5563)
05-20 11:15:05.935: E/AndroidRuntime(32533):    at android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults(ActivityThread.java:3514)

Comment: Use alertDialogue.dismiss() in onProviderEnabled

Comment: Try refering to it as ActivityName.this.alertDialogue.dismiss();
Once you have an object created, there is no reason(I think) for the Alert Dialog object to not to have cancel()  or hide() accessible. The only reason I can think of is, may be you are refering to some other object. Make sure you are refering to the same object from onProviderEnabled() call back And from switchToGPSPreferences()

Comment: You need to keep a reference of the `AlertDialog` returned by the `alertDialogue.create();` line and call `dismiss()` on that. `alertDialogue` is of type `Builder` now.

Comment: @Amr yeah I have but you didn't specified the type of alertDialogue you are using. You're using this.alertDialogue but what type of reference is this? And if it is not showing the dismiss property cast it like this and call dismiss:
((AlertDialog) alertDialogue).dismiss()

Comment: please see the update: when casting ((AlertDialog) alertDialogue).dismiss() the logcat generates errors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this Change in your code.

```
// gloabal variable of alert dialog.  
AlertDialog alert;


private void switchToGPSPreferences() {

    Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "Inside Of switchToGPSPreferences()");
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);   
    builder.setTitle("GPS Settings");
    builder.alertDialogue.setCancelable(false);
    builder.alertDialogue.setMessage(ALER_DIALOGUE_MSG);


   builder.setNeutralButton("Settings",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {

            dialog.dismiss();
            Intent gpsSettings = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            startActivityForResult(gpsSettings, GPS_SETTINGS_REQUEST_CODE);
        }
    });

    alert = builder.create();
    alert.show();

}// 
...
...
...
...
  @Override
      public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub  
          Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), USER_ENABLED_GPS, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();   
          Log.i(CURRENT_ACTIVITY, "GPS Enabled, onProviderEnabled()");  
                if (builder!= null) {   
                      // here ii want to dismiss/destroy the `alertdialoge`  
                       alert.dismiss();  
                    }

    }
```

Comment: please see the update: when casting ((AlertDialog) alertDialogue).dismiss() the logcat generates errors